# Duplicate worksheet, move it after a specific sheet, rename it based on a cell in another sheet and paste special values

Tags: vba

I would like to duplicate a worksheet named 'Hello', move it after another sheet named '<<', rename it based on a cell in 'Hello' and make all the values in the new sheet are paste special values. So far, I can't get past the first step of copying and renaming. Any ideas?

```
Sub Import_Output()

Sheets("Hello").Copy(Before:=Sheets("<<")).Name = Sheets("Hello").Range("G1").Value

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below code can be used to Copy and Past (Special) between the sheet:

```
Set Copy_From_Sheet = Worksheets("Sheet1")

Set Working_Sheet = Worksheets("Sheet2")

LastRow = Copy_From_Sheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

Copy_Col_Range = "A"
Paste_Col_Range = "A"

Copy_From_Sheet.Range(Copy_Col_Range & 2 & ":" & Copy_Col_Range & LastRow).Copy

Working_Sheet.Range(Paste_Col_Range & "2").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
```

Comment: Thank you. It works well. The part I don't understand is how to set the new sheet called Copy_Name to the Working_Sheet if the name is always changing? I'd like the duplicate worksheet to be hardcoded without formulas

Comment: Hmm lets assume you are having the sheetname to be copied in A1 of "Hello" sheet. Then use Declare variable as ```Dim SheetName``` and assign the variable with sheet name to be used from "Hello" sheet as ```SheetName = Worksheets("Hello").Cells(1, 1).Value``` and replace **working_sheet** in above answer with ```Set Working_Sheet = Worksheets(SheetName)```. So what ever sheet name is given in A1 of "Hello" sheet will be used. Thanks.. Hope this help you :)

Answer (score 1):

Hope below VBA will help you to copy the sheet completely.

```
Sub Create_Sheet()

Dim Copy_Name

'Assing the Required new Sheet name from the Base sheet ("Hello") to a variable.
'(1,1) means 1row 1column - Assign as per your req

Copy_Name = (Worksheets("Hello").Cells(1, 1).Value)
    
    sheetExists = False
    
'Looping all the sheets and checking if the sheet name already exists

     For Each Sheet In Worksheets
        If Sheet.Name = Copy_Name Then
            'if sheet name found then makring sheetexists as true
            sheetExists = True
            Exit For
       End If
     Next Sheet
    
    'first we are deleting if the sheet already exists based on sheetexists value
    If sheetExists = True Then
            Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        Set rslt = Worksheets(Copy_Name)
        rslt.Delete
            Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    End If
    
    
    
    Application.CopyObjectsWithCells = False
    'copying the base sheet after the base sheet - Plan to add your sheet name where you want to copy in after part
        Sheets("Hello").Copy after:=Sheets("Hello")
        
        'Renaming the copied sheet with the variable name
        ActiveSheet.Name = Copy_Name
        
        
        Application.CopyObjectsWithCells = True 'reset
        


End Sub
```

Thanks :)

Comment: Thank you :) How could I make the new sheet paste special values?

Comment: Please elebroate what you are trying .. the above code will help you to copy the data from one sheet and paste in another sheet as special paste.